# RESTEasy + spring, notfound exception not being caught in mapper

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, resteasy

I have a few resources on rest which works perfectly fine but when I make a REST call to an invalid URL the JBoss returns a 404 html exception. I want to change it to JSON exception response. I have tried creating mapper but the control does not reach there. I am adding my mapper code for ref.

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

/**
 * Map an exception to a {@link javax.ws.rs.core.Response}.
 *
 * @param exception the exception to map to a response.
 * @return a response mapped from the supplied exception.
 */
@Override
public Response toResponse(final NotFoundException exception) {
    Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
    info.put("msg", exception.getMessage());
    info.put("date", new Date());
    info.put("details", "The requested resource hasn't been found");

    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(info)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: How have you registered the NotFoundExceptionMapper?  Are you using class path scanning, registered it in web.xml, or detecting it through Spring?

Comment: @GregWhitaker I thought Provider annotation would register. My team has gotten rit of xml configurations mostly so i am trying to do that with annotations. Can you kindly suggest the best approach.

Comment: It depends on whether or not you have providers.scan enabled in your web.xml or if you have your DI framework configured to also scan @Provider annotations.  You are going to need to tell me how you are currently configuring Resteasy.

Comment: We are using simple annotation based registration.

Comment: I tried all the approaches but none of them worked.

Comment: All of the below approaches work.  They are copied straight out of working applications.  You are going to need to add more detail to your question if you would like help.  You need to post your web.xml, your spring configuration, and what version of resteasy you are using at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You can register `@Provider` annotated classes in a number of different ways:

1. Automatically scanned by Resteasy as a ServletContextListener.
2. Configured explicitly in web.xml as a ServletContextListener.
3. Configured explicitly as a standalone `javax.ws.rs.Application`.
4. Automatically scanned by an IOC container like Spring.

## Automatically Scanned by Resteasy

Configure your application to automatically scan for `@Provider` annotated class in your web.xml file by setting the `resteasy.scan.providers` context parameter.

```
<web-app>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
      </listener-class>
   </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**NOTE:** Do not use this if you are deploying on JBoss 7 or later.  `@Provider` is automatically enabled in version 7 and later of JBoss and using this value can cause errors during application startup.

---

## Configured Explicitly in web.xml

Providers can be explicitly registered with Resteasy in your web.xml file by setting the `resteasy.providers` context parameter.

```
<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.NotFoundExceptionMapper,com.foo.SomeOtherProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>

   ... All of the other HttpServletDispatcher and ResteasyBootstrap stuff like above.
</web-app>
```

---

## Configured Explicitly as Standalone App

If you are bootstrapping your Resteasy service using the `javax.ws.rs.Application` class you can add your provider implementations as follows:

```
 public class FooApplication extends Application
 {
     private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
     private Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<Class>();

     public FooApplication()
     { 
         classes.put(NotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
     }

     public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
     {
         return classes;
     }

     public Set<Object> getSingletons()
     {
         return singletons;
     }
 }
```

## Automatically Scanned by Spring

If you are using Spring to scan for your Resteasy providers you need to tell Spring that you are interested in `@Provider` annotations and you need to configure Spring to tell Resteasy about the beans it has scanned.

**ExceptionMapper**

You need to add an `@Component` annotation to your provider so Spring knows to scan it.

```
@Component
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> 
{
   //Implementation removed for brevity...
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- Spring Configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>com.foo.SpringConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- RESTEasy Configuration -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/v1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- RESTEasy <-> Spring Connector (Needed so that RESTEasy has access to Spring managed beans!) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- RESTEasy HTTP Request Processor Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```